# Can I add play.google.com music links to the beacon dashboard using app intent?

Tags: eddystone, google-nearby, google-beacon-platform, eddystone-url

I have been trying to add the following as a URL and an app intent, but I cant make it broadcast.

https://play.google.com/store/music/album/Jennifer_Myles_In_Due_Season?id=Bcd7upiwxohcs3sskrj73y4mnlm

I have read that play.google.com will not broadcast from a beacon, you need to use app intent. However, I don't believe app intent covers music, only apps.

Any insight into this would be much appreciated.

Comment: This may not be possible.  You might consider publishing your own intermediate wep page that links to the music item in the Play Store.

Comment: That's a good thought, but then I'll need to do the whole SSL certificate thing. Why disallow play.google.com and not give an alternative for music?

Comment: Good, question, but it probably has to be answered by somebody from Google.  As far as SSL certs go, there are plenty of free hosting sites that do this for you, such as Github pages.  You won't get your own custom domain, but given that users are just tapping on a URL, they probably won't care.

Comment: Oh wow, I never even gave github a thought.